# Converting Titanium apk to bar receive severe warnings

Tags: titanium, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I've a Titanium application that works on Android. Now, I want to make the Blackberry version.

I've tried to create a bar file in Titanium, but I use a lot of Titanium properties that are only for Android and iOS. So, the app crash.

I know you can repackage an apk to bar using [command line tools](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/preparing_android_apps_for_bbtos_1729415_11.html). I've used it and it works. It converts the apk to bar, and I able to load it in a device (Q5). My problem is when I use apk2bar command, I receive a lot of warnings with different levels (a lot of severe warnings).

Severe warnings is because Titanium use native access.

I don't understand why the result of the conversion is succeed with these warnings, and why I can install it on device without any problem/error/crash.

Is there a way to remove something from Titanium and remove these warnings?

If I upload this .bar to Blackberry word, will it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vila,
Those levels of warnings are there to let the developer know about potential issues. This does not mean that your application will not work.
Native libraries are supported in latest BlackBerry Android Runtime so you should not have issues, but don't forget to bundle them with your application.
Also, be sure to be using the latest dev tool to convert your APK to BAR FILE.

https://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/

Find here also the API support to ensuer you will not have issues with your app features
https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/